# Repeater transmit voice message/warning on input frequency?

Tags: repeater, citizens-band, duplexer, australia

I'm in the process of planning a UHF CB radio repeater. And I've heard there are ones around that  transmit a voice message/warning on their input frequency (as well as standard output channel ident) to warn/nag people against using the input in simplex mode without knowing/caring.

1. How would this be done, and how would your diplexer/cavity setup affect this?
2. I'm guessing it would mean you are blocking your repeater input while this happens?
3. Does this feature exist in commercial off the shelf products?

Comment: Hello Hayden, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: For people in the US reading this question, the OP lives in Australia, where UHF CB is a thing, and where the rules are different than they are in the US.

Comment: never seen or used a CB repeater,  but I don't think it needs to receive on what you call its input frequency while it's transmitting that warning, so there's no need for a diplexer: just shut down your receiver for the time.